# nginx proxy forward headers of proxied server

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-headers, substitution

In my nginx caching proxy I use proxy_pass to redirect from location /file.js to http://somedomain.com/file.js, and sub_filter to modify content of source file.js. How can I forward headers from http://somedomain.com/file.js?

```
location /file.js {
    proxy_pass http://somedomain.com;
    sub_filter "subject" "replacement";
    sub_filter_types "text/javascript";
    sub_filter_once off;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass_header Server;
}
```

How can I get last-modified header from original file.js?

Comment: If the backend does not supply such header then nginx is not going to invent one for you, look into the backend where such header should be generated.

Comment: On the backend last-modified header is present.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060767/http-if-modified-since-header-not-passed-to-rails-app-nginx-passenger

Comment: Tnx, m8, but not really..

Comment: The only other I could find is http://www.nginxcp.com/forums/Thread-nginx-not-sending-expiration-headers?page=2 might be a etag issue as well other then a permission thing.

Comment: sub_filter_last_modified on; did the trick..

Answer (score 0):

sub_filter_last_modified on;

Adding this option to location did the trick.